# Whose games should I collect for Scotch Opening?

Tags: opening, scotch-game

I have been adopting the Scotch opening recently with some moderate success. I would like to know whose games should I look at to have a good understanding. I see that [Nakamura](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=&playercomp=white&pid=10084&player=&pid2=&player2=&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=C45&eco=&result=) and [Kasparov](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?yearcomp=exactly&year=&playercomp=white&pid=15940&player=&pid2=&player2=&movescomp=exactly&moves=&opening=C45&eco=&result=) deploy Scotch reasonably often. Apart from him, I was surprised to see that Tal used Scotch in only 3 games and Fischer never. I was under the impression that Scotch gives rise to dynamic active position and hence my surprise.

Comment: Scotch game or Scotch gambit? If the later https://www.amazon.co.uk/Scotch-Gambit-Energetic-Aggressive-System/dp/1941270743 contains a number of annotated games

Answer (score 4):

I religiously play scotch in e4/e5 games. Sergei Rublevsky is the star I follow.

Comment: Thanks, anyone else preferably a world champion or some recent top 10 player

Answer (score 2):

Magnus Carlsen has some games as White you might look for. 
GM Parimarjan Negi authored a DVD on the Scotch and has himself played it on many occasions.

Fischer loved the Ruy Lopez so didn't have much need for the Scotch, and in general fashion has favored the Ruy Lopez. Then Kasparov resurrected the Scotch (he even had an affair with the Evan's Gambit) and it saw new light.

Answer (score 2):

I generally prefer GM Negi Parimarjan, who is the master of the Scotch Opening and, as mentioned above, he has created a DVD series.

He has played Scotch lots of times.

Answer (score 1):

Kasparov has some good examples. Se http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chesscollection?cid=1017006

Answer (score 1):

There is a new book on the Scotch by Alexander Khalifman (who is sort of an ex world champion).